# Currency formatting in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Could you help me with formatting amount figures in the Laravel blade based on model currency, please? Value is stored as double and currency as char(3) '`usd`','`eur`','`czk`','`huf`'...

The projects has to be displayed in given currency format:

```
| 1 | project A | $1,250.00   |
| 2 | project B | €6,000.00   |
| 3 | project C | 1,250.00CZK |
```

PHP `money_format` uses locale where I want to use project specific currency in each row or each project page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if you use vuejs it makes it a breeze i would highly recommend it

Comment: I'll try to clarify. what i need is a formatter to format value of the project based on project currency. by using php money_format i have to set locale first and then echo value which will be formated but in blade when i have list of different projects I will have to set locale as many times as I number of rows in a table. this looks hairy for me, I can bet there is simpler approach like format_value($project->value, $project->currency) returning proper format for currencies.

Comment: @SariYono i wish I had VueJS implemented, but I am not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own transformers, something like this:

## In your controller

```
public function getRows(Request $request, CurrencyTransformer $transformer) {
    
    // get data

    $rows = Model::where('some', 'condition')->get()->toArray();

    $data = $transformer->transformCollection($rows);

    return view('some.view', compact('data'));
}
```

## Create a abstract transformer class

```
abstract class Transformer
{
    
    public function transformCollection(array $items)
    {
        return array_map([$this, 'transform'], $items);
    }

    public abstract function transform($item);
}
```

## create a currency transformer

```
class CurrencyTransformer extends Transformer
{
    
    public function transform($item) {

        switch($item['currency']) {
            case "usd":
                $item['value'] = "$" . $item['value'];
                break;
            ...
        }
  
        return $item;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, after some research I think I will go wit the helper function for formatting all currency values and use it in blade. so I can use it {{ formatPrice($project->value) }} then my prefixes or suffixes for different currencies will be appended as per rules in switch block